# What is apr_pool?

Tags: api, svn, apr

Whis is `apr_pool` in the Subversion API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

APR stands for [Apache portable Runtime](http://apr.apache.org/), the [pool](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.3/group__apr__pools.html) is a memory allocation systems.